# Match comma separated column values

Tags: mysql, sql

Note: Data is already stored in this format.

I'm trying to match two comma separated values.

Table records:

```
user_id    state_id      city_id      role_id
  1        1,2,3         1,2          3,4  
  2        5,6,8,10      9,11,15      1,2
  3        7,8           10           2,5
```

I want to match column values with given values.

Each column should match one or more values.

Tried:

```
  SELECT user_id
    FROM users 
    WHERE  
    CONCAT(',', state_id, ',') LIKE '%,5,10,%' AND 
    CONCAT(',', city_id, ',') LIKE '%,9,15,%' AND
    CONCAT(',', role_id, ',') LIKE '%,1,%'
```

Expected output is user id "2" as it is matching given values but above query generating empty result.

Comment: Never, ever store data as comma separated items. It will only cause you lots of trouble.

Comment: I know but data is already stored in this format hence have to work with this only.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I match a comma separated list against a value?](//stackoverflow.com/q/1142246/https://stackoverflow.com/q/1142246/90527)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `find_in_set`:

```
  SELECT user_id
    FROM users 
    WHERE  
    find_in_set('5', state_id) <> 0 AND find_in_set('10', state_id) <> 0 AND 
    find_in_set('9', city_id) <> 0 AND find_in_set('15', city_id) <> 0 AND
    find_in_set('1', role_id) <> 0
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=64af26024153cdf82bbca549e92e86f7)

But as a general advice, you should normalise your table. Check [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad#:%7E:text=Comma%2Dseparated%20is%20just%20as,with%20consideration%20of%20the%20consequences.)

Comment: Ok but given values are not fixed they are coming dynamicly.

Comment: @glitchy then build the where clause "dynamically".

Comment: @SalmanA Ok. will it impact the performance as it will create long query?

Comment: @glitchy you have a poor database design to begin with. performance should be least of your concerns; get accurate results at least.

Answer (score 0):

This model not is the best, but since you not defined it and you only need to query....

```
SELECT user_id
  FROM users
  WHERE
  state_id LIKE '%5%10%' AND
  city_id LIKE '%9%15%' AND
  role_id LIKE '%1%'
```

PS. Take care about your performance, because multiples LIKE in a text field (I'm thinking it's a varchar!) might create other issues.